# Yup validation with dynamic fields on React-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have dynamic fields on React project. They have created with React-hook-form. Now I want to add validation here. But I researched a lot of information, but none of them worked. I have a form, and the user writes his name and surname. After if the user clicks the `Add` button, then all `children's name` fields must not be empty or remove these fields.

Parent component

```
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  surname: yup.string().required(),
});

const PersonalInformation = () => {
  const {handleSubmit, register, formState: { errors }} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      childrenNames: [{ childrenName: '',}],
    },
  });

    const handleAppend = useCallback(() => append({childrenName: '',}), []);

  const removeFields = useCallback((index) => remove(index), []);

  const { append, remove, fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'childrenNames',
  });

  const nameInput = useMemo(
    () => <Input id="name" inputName="Your name" register={register} name="name" error={errors?.name?.message} />,
    [errors?.name],
  );

  const surNameInput = useMemo(
    () => <Input id="surname" inputName="Your surname" register={register} name="surname" error={errors?.surname?.message} />
    [errors?.surname],
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={4}>{nameInput}</Col>
        <Col xs={4}>{surNameInput}</Col>
      </Row>
      {fields?.map((field, index) => (
        <Row key={field?.id} className="mt-5">    
          <Col xs={4}>
            <Input
              inputName="Fin kod"
              name={`childrenNames[${index}].childrenName`}
              register={register}
            />
          </Col>
        
          <div className="final-buttons">
            <div className="btn-start">
              <button onClick={handleAppend} type="button">
                + Add
              </button>
            </div>
            {index > 0 || checkIndex ? (
              <div>
                <button onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>Remove</button>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </Row>
      ))}
    </form>

}
```

Child component

```
const Input = ({ error, inputName, id, register, type = 'text', name, placeholder, required }) => {
...
return (
  <div className="form-input">
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        {inputName}
        {required && <span>*</span>}
      </label>
      <input type={inputType} {...register(name)} id={id} placeholder={placeholder} className={`${error ? 'error-status' : null}`} />
      </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Firstly, I have changed yup

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  surname: yup.string().required(),
  childrenNames: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      childrenName: yup.string().required(),
    }),
  ),
});
```

After I sent an error message as a props. But I got an undefined error, that's why I wrote with condition.

```
     {fields?.map((field, index) => (
        <Row key={field?.id} className="mt-5">    
          <Col xs={4}>
            <Input
              inputName="Fin kod"
              name={`childrenNames[${index}].childrenName`}
              register={register}
              error={errors?.childrenNames && errors.childrenNames[index]?.childrenName?.message}
            />
        </Col>
      </Row>
     }
```

and in the child component, I used an error props.

```
const Input = ({ error, inputName, id, register, type = 'text', name, placeholder, required }) => {
...
return (
  <div className="form-input">
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        {inputName}
        {required && <span>*</span>}
      </label>
      <input type={inputType} {...register(name)} id={id} placeholder={placeholder} className={`${error ? 'error-status' : null}`} />
      <span className="error">{error}</span>
   </div>
)
}
```